# Kosher flat mates. Is it a thing?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I am certain that this is very case by case and by different locations, but I am curious if it is "commonplace" to have a roommate in the frum world. I am essentially a baal teshuvah with fairly limited means. I am not certain if its common in the modern frum world to have roommates or not and not certain how to go about looking into this. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but I can’t tell if this question is halachic, hashkafic, etc? Sorry but for now I vote to close for being off topic since this is a very broad topic that doesn’t seem to have much to do with either Jewish law, practice, theology etc.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is appropriate for you, as a baal teshuvah, to have a frum roommate instead of a "non-frum" roommate?

Comment: In Israel this is a common arrangement, and when taking a roommate whether they're shower Shabbat and Kashrut is an important factor

Comment: Of course it's a thing! To stay *frum* you have to hang around with a good *chevra*. Good luck!